# Azure Service Bus: How to keep the message send from sender is FIFO

Tags: message-queue, azureservicebus, fifo

I have read a few questions from StackOverflow. They said we can enabled the Session Support to the queue to keep the message FIFO. Some mention the ordering cannot be guaranteed. To make sure the message processed in order we have to deal with manual during the processing by the timestamp.

Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Service Bus Queue itself follows FIFO. In some cases, the processing of the messages may not be sequential. If you are sure that the size of the payload will be consistent, then you can go with the normal Queues, which will process the messages in order(works for me).

If there will be change in payload size between the messages, it is preferred to go with Session enabled Queues as [Sean Feldman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59563/sean-feldman) mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

To send/receive messages in FIFO mode, you need to enable enable "Require Sessions" on the queue and use Message Sessions to send/receive messages. The timestamp doesn't matter. What matters is the session.

- Upon sending, setting message's `SessionId`
- Upon receiving, either receive any session using `MessageReceiver` or a specific session using lower level API (`SessionClient`) and specifying session ID.

A good start would be to read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions) and have a look at this [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/blob/master/samples/DotNet/GettingStarted/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/BasicSendReceiveUsingQueueClient/readme.md).